# Importing files from other directory in python?

Tags: python-2.7, path, directory, python-import

I have following directory structure:

A
|
|--B--Hello.py
|
|--C--Message.py

Now if the path of root directory A is not fixed, how can i import "Hello.py" from B to "Message.py" in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I suggest to add empty `__init__.py` file into every directory with python sources. It will prevent many issues with imports because this is how the [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) work in Python:

In your case it this should look like this:

```bash
A
├── B
│   ├── Hello.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── C
│   ├── Message.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

Let's say the Hello.py contains the function foo:

```py
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

and the `Message.py` tries to use it:

```py
from ..B.Hello import foo

print(foo())
```

**The first way** to make it work is to let the Python interpreter to do his job and to [handle package](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) constructing:

```
~ $ python -m A.C.Message
```

**Another option** is to add your `Hello.py` file into [list of known sources](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) with the following code:

```py
# Message.py file

import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

from B.Hello import foo

print(foo())
```

In this case you can execute it with

```bash
~/A/C $ python Message.py
```